# Need a way to add teams and solo gameplay. Also any idea on making a main menu with tkinter for playing as team or solo

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and python. I somehow followed a guide and came up with a snake game. This game runs great. However, there are a few things that I need to add to make it much better.

First of all, I want to add some sort of start screen menu. Want it to have buttons. This start screen will tie into my next addition.

I am wanting to add a scoring system for teams or solo. I need it to selectable from the main screen. Like "play as a team" or "play on your own" buttons. If the team button is pressed then there will be 5 rounds, one round for each player. I have seen somewhat how to make the main menu screen using Tkinter. However, the other part about the teams and solo part seems to baffle me. Can't find a way to do it and can't find a guide online. I'm kinda stuck here.

Any help will be greatly needed and accepted. I will post the game code below so you guys can see it.

Thanks,

```
# import required modules
import turtle
import time
import random
import tkinter as tk

delay = 0.1
score = 0
high_score = 0
 
 
 
# Creating a window screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Game made by name")
wn.bgcolor("coral")
# the width and height can be put as user's choice
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)
 
# head of the snake
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.shape("square")
head.color("black")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "Stop"
 
# food in the game
food = turtle.Turtle()
colors = random.choice(['red', 'yellow'])
shapes = random.choice(['square', 'triangle', 'circle'])
food.speed(0)
food.shape(shapes)
food.color(colors)
food.penup()
food.goto(0, 100)
 
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 250)
pen.write("My Score : 0  High Score : 0", align="center",
          font=("segoe print", 24, "bold"))
 
 
 
# assigning key directions
def group():
    if head.direction != "down":
        head.direction = "up"
 
 
def godown():
    if head.direction != "up":
        head.direction = "down"
 
 
def goleft():
    if head.direction != "right":
        head.direction = "left"
 
 
def goright():
    if head.direction != "left":
        head.direction = "right"
 
 
def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y+20)
    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y-20)
    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x-20)
    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x+20)
 
 
         
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(group, "w")
wn.onkeypress(godown, "s")
wn.onkeypress(goleft, "a")
wn.onkeypress(goright, "d")
 
segments = []
 
 
 
# Main Gameplay
while True:
    wn.update()
    if head.xcor() > 290 or head.xcor() < -290 or head.ycor() > 290 or head.ycor() < -290:
        time.sleep(1)
        head.goto(0, 0)
        head.direction = "Stop"
        colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue'])
        shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle'])
        for segment in segments:
            segment.goto(1000, 1000)
        segments.clear()
        score = 0
        delay = 0.1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
            score, high_score), align="center", font=("segoe print", 24, "bold"))
    if head.distance(food) < 20:
        x = random.randint(-270, 270)
        y = random.randint(-270, 270)
        food.goto(x, y)
 
        # Adding segment
        new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        new_segment.speed(0)
        new_segment.shape("square")
        new_segment.color("lime")  # tail colour
        new_segment.penup()
        segments.append(new_segment)
        delay -= 0.00001
        score += 1
        if score > high_score:
            high_score = score
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
            score, high_score), align="center", font=("segoe print", 24, "bold"))
    # Checking for head collisions with body segments
    for index in range(len(segments)-1, 0, -1):
        x = segments[index-1].xcor()
        y = segments[index-1].ycor()
        segments[index].goto(x, y)
    if len(segments) > 0:
        x = head.xcor()
        y = head.ycor()
        segments[0].goto(x, y)
    move()
    for segment in segments:
        if segment.distance(head) < 20:
            time.sleep(1)
            head.goto(0, 0)
            head.direction = "stop"
            colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
            shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle'])
            for segment in segments:
                segment.goto(1000, 1000)
            segment.clear()
 
            score = 0
            delay = 0.1
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score : {} High Score : {} ".format(
                score, high_score), align="center", font=("segoe print", 24, "bold"))
    time.sleep(delay)
 
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: a good question.  what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @D.L I have tried doing the main menu GUI but the Tkinter is grey and won't run. I'm kinda new to this and have been looking online and can't seem to fix this issue. I have been stuck with this for 1 week and have been baffled by it. No idea where to make this work and implement it. Sorry for this

Comment: ah, okay.  i was going to comment that `tkinter` and `turtle` are two alternatives (as is `pygame` amongst many others). So really, you should stick to one and not mix then...  this would be a good starter guide to selecting one:  https://analyticsindiamag.com/top-9-python-frameworks-for-game-development/

Comment: @D.L Thank you for this reply. I have been looking at the link you sent and the advice you have mentioned. However, I am baffled to adding more players. I have an idea, where if the player select the team option in the menu (I will make the menu last) then there will be a new round for each player of the team and the scores are added up to a team score. Been looking on how to do such team thing for snake and again seem to be stuck. If you know how I can start with such team options in code, it will be greatly accepted.

Comment: you would expect to do this with `Classes` where each player is a different `class` instance. This is only a pointer in the right direction as the complete answer would be rather large.